# можно ли через модуль VK получить ответ в виде xml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет! есть модуль для Вконтакте https://github.com/dimka665/vk , ответ присылает в формате JSON. интересует, возможно ли получить ответ в формате xml? API Вконтакте дает эту возможность через запрос вида

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get.xml(user_ids=1)
```

Но через сам модуль не получается запросить xml строкой вида

```
api.users.get.xml(user_ids=1)
```

Ошибка: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Весь код:

```
import vk

session = vk.AuthSession()
api = vk.API(session)
getme = api.users.get.xml(user_ids=1, fields = 'sex,verified,about,bdate,connections')
print (getme)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно не получиться - модуль так просто не умеет. Если посмотреть в [код](https://github.com/dimka665/vk/blob/398dab89f5dd0909ba75cc60c4fbd3e6357f1f9a/vk/session.py) в районе 35 строки - то там явно запрашивается json и нет попыток делать тоже для xml. Так что, либо дописывайте текущую библиотеку, либо ищите другую/пишите другую.

Comment: жаль, спасибо!.

Answer (score 1):

Используй библиотеку vkAPI

Я только что добавил туда это расширение, так что будет работать и так и так)